# comparing dates by converting them using strtotime

Tags: php

i need to compare $startdate and $fin_date.But the problem is that when i use strtotime it dosent show any value. while  on doing strtotime on $stardate it returns a result as 1420502400.

```
$sqldt="select to_char(sysdate-2,'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual";
$stmtdt = $obj->executeQuery($sqldt);
$rowdt = oci_fetch_array($stmtdt,OCI_BOTH);


$startdate = date('d/m/y', strtotime($rowdt[0]));               


$date11 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/y", $startdate2);
$enddate=$date11->modify("- $row_count days")->format('d/m/y');

$fin_date=strtotime($enddate);
```

for eg if $enddate=30/05/15 after  strtotime($enddate)= (no result).please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this code :

```
$date1=date('d/m/y');
$date2='1/06/15';
if(strtotime($date1)<strtotime($date2))
   echo '1 is small='.strtotime($date1).','.$date1;
else
   echo '2 is small='.strtotime($date2).','.$date2;
```

If this doesn't works you can also use **diff** function(of datetime class) :

```
$date1=date('d/m/y');
$date2='01/06/15';

$datetime1 = new DateTime($date1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date2);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$dateDiff = $interval->format('%R%a');

if($dateDiff == 0)
{
   echo "$date1 is equal to the $date2";
}
else
{
   echo ($dateDiff > 0)? "$date2 is greater than the $date1": "$date1 is greater than the $date2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dd/mm/yyyy date format is not working with strtotime function. Please use mm/dd/yyyy OR dd-mm-yyyy format

"Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed."

You can use by replacing

```
$startdate = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate );
```